# Why couldn't Tuvok be cured by the holodeck?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, vulcan, holodeck

Near the end of *Voyager*, Tuvok required fal-tor-voh to heal his mind. This requires

> a vulcan,

which the crew considered unavailable. Why was this considered impossible? Why can the holodeck not solve this?

Comment: Why would a hologram work?

Comment: On several occasions Spock, a half-Vulcan, was able to meld with various non-living entities such as NOMAD, and V'Ger so it is probable that it was simply too difficult to generate a suitable or compatible donor mind in the holodeck with the technology levels available to the crew.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided in *Endgame* itself: the treatment required a mind-meld with a compatible Vulcan, preferably a blood relative. The other Vulcan(s) on board were not compatible.

Here's the relevant quote:

> **TUVOK**: Your concern is appreciated, Captain, but premature. It will be several years before the symptoms become serious. Until then, the Doctor can manage my condition with medication.
>
> **JANEWAY**: Is it true what the Admiral said? That there's a cure in the Alpha Quadrant?
>
> **TUVOK**: It is called a fal-tor-voh, and it requires a mind meld with another Vulcan.
>
> **JANEWAY**: What about the other Vulcans on Voyager?
>
> **TUVOK**: None of them are compatible.
>
> **JANEWAY**: But members of your family are? If you knew that returning to the Alpha Quadrant was your only chance for recovery, why didn't you object when I asked you to help find a way to destroy the hub?

The holodeck creates optical illusions and puppets controlled by force fields; it cannot create biological life. (Or, in Captain Picard's own words from *Insurrection*: "...a computer-driven image created by photons and force fields". Assuming you're content to take Captain Picard at his word.)

Extrapolating very lightly from this: if any random real-life flesh-and-blood Vulcan was not sufficient, a non-living holographic Vulcan facsimile would not be sufficient.